# Syntax error when putting HTML data in Oledb c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, oledb, html-agility-pack

what am basically trying to do here is to scrap user opinion and put each user opinion one by one in each row. Code seems to be alright. But everytime I try to run it gives me syntax error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsciW.png)

And this is my code:

```
foreach (var item in HeaderNames)
        {


            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Review (Rev,Url) values('" + item.InnerText + "','" + txtURL.Text + "')";
                MessageBox.Show("this is test");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Comment: propbably your text contains ' chars. try to insert with parameters. it's anyway better to avoid injection.

Comment: parameters, parameters, parameters...